# Cannot create Amazon S3 Bucket in specified region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

On my macOS Sierra:

```
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket testbucket --region us-west-1
{
    "Location": "/testbucket"
}
```

Then...

```
$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket testbucket
{
    "LocationConstraint": null
}
```

The weird thing is if I were to check my [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-1), it would show my bucket created but in US East(N. Virginia region). Is the us-west-1 region not available or something?

If it makes a difference, from 
`$ aws configure`
I can see that my default region name is `us-west-1`

```
Default region name [us-west-1]:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html): *"Regions outside of us-east-1 require the appropriate LocationConstraint to be specified in order to create the bucket in the desired region"*

Try:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --region us-west-1 --bucket textbucket --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks to work (and proceed to the next error, which is the same one I got when I manually tried to create the bucket through the console): `An error occurred (OperationAborted) when calling the CreateBucket operation: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.` However, this is a different question and I'll spend some time debugging that.

Comment: The cause of my error above looks to be because I'm trying to create the bucket too soon after deleting one with the same name.